# Python - pack only takes effect after the method is complete

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on a small game where you enter some amount n, and you get n color frames with random colors. After 3 seconds, the user is prompted to attempt to recall the order of the color frames.

*Note that the events after the countdown are not yet implemented (there should be no issue with that).*

I have a method that hides the Entry field and confirmation button, displays the colors, and does a countdown:

```
def startgame(colornumber): #colornumber is the amount of frames
    ...
    colors=[] #array of "Frame" elements
    #loop that creates the colored frames
    for i in range (0, colornumber):
        colors.append(Frame(window, width=60, height=60, background=randomcolor()))
        colors[i].pack(side=LEFT)

    #randomcolor() is a method that returns a random color string
    #like "white" or "red"

    #countdown loop
    for i in range(0, 3):
        time.sleep(1)   #do nothing for 1 second
        label.configure(text="ASD")    #Count down
        print(str(3-i))
    label.configure(text="What was the order? Click on the colors to choose")
```

The button calls the function like so:

```
colorNumberInput = Entry(window)
colorNumberInput.pack()
buttonConfirmNumber = Button(window, ..., command=lambda: startgame(int(colornumberInput.get()))
buttonConfirmNumber.pack()
```

For some reason, the effects of the statement `color[i].pack(side=LEFT)` only take place after the method has finished executing; that is, after the countdown loop finishes. The result is that the colors appear after the countdown, and not before it. I tried putting a `print` statement into the loop that creates the color frames, and it does execute anyway.

Why do the does `pack(element)` show the widgets only after the method it is called in has ended? Is there any way that I can work around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter is only able to refresh the display by responding to events. It can't respond to events while your code is running or the program is sleeping.

A quick fix is to call `window.update_idletasks()` whenever you want the screen refreshed. That's not usually the best solution, but it often is Good Enough.

Comment: "Good enough" in some cases, but `time.sleep` + `tkinter` is almost always terrible; spending three seconds with a completely non-responsive GUI is extremely user hostile.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: no argument there.